# Cloudformation template demands network but does not accept it

Tags: aws-cloudformation

When creating a AWS::ECS::Service inside the Cloudformation templates, I require a networkconfiguration to be filled in, otherwise the stack creation does not start.
According to the [networkconfiguration documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-networkconfiguration.html), this can and should be an [AwsVpcConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-networkconfiguration.html).

I did this and tried to run the following template snippet:

```
Type: 'AWS::ECS::Service'
Properties:
  Cluster: !Ref MyCluster
  DesiredCount: 1
  LaunchType: 'FARGATE'
  NetworkConfiguration:
    AwsvpcConfiguration:
      AssignPublicIp: 'ENABLED'
      Subnets:
        - !Ref MySubnet
```

When I run this stack, the error returned is:

```
Encountered unsupported property AwsVpcConfiguration
```

So I can't make any stack without this option but the stack itself tells me the option is illegal. What can I do about this?

Comment: CloudFormation properties are case sensitive. While the casing of `AwsvpcConfiguration` in your snippet actually looks correct, the casing in the error message implies a template snippet might have been tried with incorrect casing

Comment: Does your task use `awsvpc` network mode? You haven't provided its template.

Comment: @Marcin: Yes I use the awsvpc  in this case. I did not mention the rest because I thought it would not matter. That is to say, when removing the service component every other thing runs just fine.

Comment: @PatMyron: The snippet above is the only piece of code that referred the configuration.

Comment: @Ludo21South The snippet looks fine.

Comment: @Marcin: which is exactly why I asked around. Still not solved, for now I'm just leaving the services out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AwsvpcConfiguration` instead of `AwsVpcConfiguration`. (Note the `v` in `vpc`.)

Comment: Might sound dumb but, I already did? (see my snippet in the original post)

Comment: And you're still getting `Encountered unsupported property AwsVpcConfiguration`?
This is hard to believe. Where would CF get the misspelled property name?
Please double-check your template.

Comment: I kind of dropped the services about a week ago, as mentioned in my other comment. As soon as I return to this topic and method I will make sure to test this piece of code to see if this issue still emerges. Code revision tells me the lower case "v" was always in the code. Will let you know when I revisit this topic.